# Как установить свой обработчик кнопки?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Есть кнопка. Как через сабклассинг установить ей свой обработчик wndProc?

Comment: `SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)newProc);`, где `newProc` — новый обработчик. Сам `SetWindowLong()` вернёт адрес предыдущего обработчика, который надо преобразовать в `WNDPROC` и вызывать из новой оконной процедуры вместо `DefWindowProc()`.